# Parsing JSON file using json_decode

Tags: php, json

I am having an issue with parsing my JSON file with the PHP function json_decode. **I am currently seeing only the last object in the nested JSON array (BANNER2)**. I realize i am using duplicate keys in the JSON file but i am clueless on how to structure the JSON file in a different way.

my JSON file:

```
{  
    "project_filename":"testzip",
    "data":[  
       {  
          "title":"Quebec",
          "displayTag":"H1",
          "css":"",
          "type":"header",
          "display_title":"",
          "data":[  
             {  
                "title":"BANNER1",
                "displayTag":"h2",
                "css":"hidden",
                "type":"collapse",
                "display_title":"",
                "data":[  
                   {  
                      "title":"160x600",
                      "displayTag":"p",
                      "display_title":"DESCRIPTION",
                      "filename":"300x250",
                      "type":"banner",
                      "source":"pages/300x250/index.html",
                      "width":"300",
                      "height":"250",
                      "controls":true
                   }
                ],
                "title":"BANNER2",
                "displayTag":"h2",
                "css":"hidden",
                "type":"collapse",
                "display_title":"",
                "data":[  
                   {  
                      "title":"160x600",
                      "displayTag":"p",
                      "display_title":"DESCRIPTION",
                      "filename":"300x250",
                      "type":"banner",
                      "source":"pages/300x250/index.html",
                      "width":"300",
                      "height":"250",
                      "controls":true
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

my PHP file:

```
$JSONdata = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($JSONdata['data'] as $key => $dt) {
    foreach ($dt['data'] as $data) {

    // use the JSON values in the $dt variable and do stuff with it
```

Comment: The problem certainly lies in how this JSON was constructed. While structurally ok, it's technically not even valid. Looks like something went afoul with the nesting at least.

Comment: *I realize i am using duplicate keys in the JSON file* - if you've got duplicated keys, then what you've got is not valid JSON. The items should be in an array.

Comment: I got `SyntaxError: Duplicate key 'title' on line 26`

Comment: you should have an array of objects, not repeat the keys. How did you create this invalid JSON in the first place? No JSON encoding library will do this.

Comment: The idea is that i need the first array to contain the region -> banner number -> size. So each region needs it's own set of banner numbers and sizes within those banner numbers. (sorry for the confusing explanation)

Comment: If you're constructing this format yourself, try and avoid using generic words like **data**. Everything in the string is data. How about a "banners" key, that points to an array of objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two banners should be separate objects in the array, not duplicate keys in a single object. Object keys have to be unique.

```
{  
    "project_filename":"testzip",
    "data":[  
       {  
          "title":"Quebec",
          "displayTag":"H1",
          "css":"",
          "type":"header",
          "display_title":"",
          "data":[  
             {  
                "title":"BANNER1",
                "displayTag":"h2",
                "css":"hidden",
                "type":"collapse",
                "display_title":"",
                "data":[  
                   {  
                      "title":"160x600",
                      "displayTag":"p",
                      "display_title":"DESCRIPTION",
                      "filename":"300x250",
                      "type":"banner",
                      "source":"pages/300x250/index.html",
                      "width":"300",
                      "height":"250",
                      "controls":true
                   }
                ]
             },{
                "title":"BANNER2",
                "displayTag":"h2",
                "css":"hidden",
                "type":"collapse",
                "display_title":"",
                "data":[  
                   {  
                      "title":"160x600",
                      "displayTag":"p",
                      "display_title":"DESCRIPTION",
                      "filename":"300x250",
                      "type":"banner",
                      "source":"pages/300x250/index.html",
                      "width":"300",
                      "height":"250",
                      "controls":true
                   }
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: can't believe i didn't see that. Thank you!